# Download zip/tar Github repository with .git metadata?

Tags: git, zip, tar, github

I need to download zip/tar Git repositories from Github and get not just the source but also the .git directory.

I'm aware I could use `git clone`, but this is for an tool that runs on systems that may not necessarily have `git` installed. Zipped repos are downloaded (doesn't require `git`) and after that I would like the .git directory there so users who do have `git` have a fully working git repo and can start branching, etc.

Anybody know of a Github endpoint or flag that includes the .git dir in zips?

Comment: [relevant?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106012/download-a-single-folder-or-directory-from-a-github-repo)

Comment: Interesting that svn can be used here, though users without Git installed are unlikely to have SVN either. Perhaps I'll just make Git a requirement.

Comment: while there is probably not a git endpoint, it wouldn't be difficult to model. `git clone {repo} && zip {reponame}`. I'm pretty sure the reason the folder is omitted is that it is intended as a release artifact, even if it's not common to include baked-in dependencies (which as long as you're using a dependency manager and build-system that supports clearing baked-in-deps is not a problem either)